# Guidelines for android development

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-2.1

I am working on android development for past 6 months, but so far my skill level is very low.
I need some guidelines on how to advance my level.
What books should I read?
and also do I need to gear up my JAVA knowledge?

(I am looking for tutorial links for android development OR book names)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah its hard to learn at first but we have to...
You said u are 6 months expericed u may know well about developer.android site.
You download some pdfs,

[The Android Developer's Cookbook](http://idata.ws/news/the_android_developer_s_cookbook/2010-11-30-366)

[Android in Action](http://idata.ws/news/android_in_action/2011-01-15-535)

KATHY SEIRRA e-book- for java will be good.

i think the above books will be useful to you.Google is the best master where you will find best tutorial for different topics.:P

ALL THE BEST.

Answer (score 1):

**Practice** and only practice.

Remember: Practice makes man perfect.

For android developer guide see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html).
[This](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html) is also a good guide.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to learn is to develop apps. Try to download some apps from google play and recreate them. Thats the only way to learn.

I tried listening to some videos, but it made me very impatient. Finally I closed all the books, videos and started developing apps. N that way I learned faster.

If not for anything try building a library for yourself which you can use for your later projects.